# Can we have two primary keys in one Foreign key field?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

My db hierarchy is like Group -> Branch -> department. 
Employee and Roles are different table ,tbl_Employee having FK groupid,branchid,  departmentid and RoleId. If I assign an employee as a '1' which is a groupHead according to Roles table then I have to provide this employee's branchId and depId as well. But all Branches of the particular group comes under him . So I was thinking of writing all the branchIds which comes under him. How should I proceed ?

Comment: I don't understand this question. What does the title mean? Do you mean one foreign key reference that references two different tables? Or do you mean you want to store more than one value into one column? And how does the content of this question relate to the title?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen  Please read it once more. Its correct.

Comment: Why not model it as an Employee with null `departmentID` is attached to the branch, and an Employee with null `branchID` and `departmentID` is attached to the group, and for each, it's automatically implied that they have all items below that? You could even have a check constraint that ensures e.g. that they only have `NULL`s in particular columns where the `RoleID` is correct.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever- But how can I pass NULL values in FK fields which are in fact primary keys of other table and Primary keys cannot be NULL.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes I mean more than one value into one column. What does the foreign key column holds ? Primary keys of other table.

Comment: A foreign key holds **one key**, hence the name. You can't have multiple values in one column, regardless of it being a foreign key or not. So you're going to have to go with something like @Damien_The_Unbeliever 's example, implying the relationship through a join on that other table.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen- How to check constraint ? I am not getting data in grid on asp.net as db method is returning NULL in Dataset. The reason being same. FK cannot be NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a structure like this:

```
create table Groups (
    GroupID char(2) not null primary key
)
create table Branches (
    GroupID char(2) not null foreign key references Groups (GroupID),
    BranchID char(2) not null primary key,
    constraint UQ_Branch_XRef UNIQUE (GroupID,BranchID)
)
create table Departments (
    GroupID char(2) not null foreign key references Groups (GroupID),
    BranchID char(2) not null foreign key references Branches (BranchID),
    DepartmentID char(2) not null primary key,
    constraint UQ_Department_XRef UNIQUE (GroupID,BranchID,DepartmentID),
    constraint FK_Department_Branch_XRef FOREIGN KEY (GroupID,BranchID)
        references Branches (GroupID,BranchID)
)
create table Employees (
    EmployeeID char(2) not null primary key,
    GroupID char(2) not null references Groups (GroupID),
    BranchID char(2) null references Branches (BranchID),
    DepartmentID char(2) null references Departments (DepartmentID),
    RoleID int not null,
    constraint FK_Employee_Branch_XRef FOREIGN KEY (GroupID,BranchID)
        references Branches (GroupID,BranchID),
    constraint FK_Employee_Department_XRef FOREIGN KEY (GroupID,BranchID,
                                                        DepartmentID) 
        references Departments (GroupID,BranchID,DepartmentID),
    constraint CK_AppropriateRole CHECK (
        (RoleID = 1 and BranchID is null and DepartmentID is null) or
        (RoleID = 2 and BranchID is not null and DepartmentID is null) or
        (RoleID = 3 and BranchID is not null and DepartmentID is not null)
    )
)
```

And then populate it like this:

```
insert into Groups (GroupID) values ('aa'),('bb')
insert into Branches (GroupID,BranchID) values
('aa','cc'),('aa','dd'),('bb','ee'),('bb','ff')
insert into Departments (GroupID,BranchID,DepartmentID) values
('aa','cc','gg'),
('aa','cc','hh'),
('aa','dd','ii'),
('bb','ee','jj'),
('bb','ff','kk'),
('bb','ff','ll')
```

And insert some valid employees

```
insert into Employees (EmployeeID,GroupID,BranchID,DepartmentID,RoleID) values
('mm','aa',null,null,1),
('nn','aa','dd',null,2),
('oo','bb','ee','jj',3)
```

But then you can't insert invalid rows:

```
insert into Employees (EmployeeID,GroupID,BranchID,DepartmentID,RoleID) values
('pp','bb',null,null,3)
insert into Employees (EmployeeID,GroupID,BranchID,DepartmentID,RoleID) values
('qq','aa','cc','hh',1)
insert into Employees (EmployeeID,GroupID,BranchID,DepartmentID,RoleID) values
('rr','aa','cc','ii',3)
```

And then it's implied that `'mm'` is attached to group `'aa'` and all branches and departments under it, `'nn'` is attached to branch `'dd'` of group `'aa'` and all departments under that, and `'oo'` is in department `'jj'` of branch `'ee'` of group `'bb'`.

---

Whenever you store a `NULL` in (a column of) a foreign key, in SQL Server, then SQL Server doesn't enforce that foreign key.

---

### The Constraints

There are 16 constraints in the 4 above tables, and most of them serve an important purpose. I'll ignore the primary keys since they're just fulfilling their usual role.

```
create table Branches (
    GroupID char(2) not null foreign key references Groups (GroupID),
```

Just a plain foreign key. Nothing special yet

```
    ...
    constraint UQ_Branch_XRef UNIQUE (GroupID,BranchID)
```

We need this unique constraint so that foreign keys can reference this table by both columns, so that we can cross-check that where a `BranchID` is used, it's used with the *correct* `GroupID`.

```
)
create table Departments (
    GroupID char(2) not null foreign key references Groups (GroupID),
    BranchID char(2) not null foreign key references Branches (BranchID),
```

The above two foreign key references aren't strictly necessary. The other FK defined below on this table will also ensure that the values are valid. But they are the "natural" FKs that most people would define. Whether you keep them or not is a matter of preference and possibly performance.

```
    ...
    constraint UQ_Department_XRef UNIQUE (GroupID,BranchID,DepartmentID),
```

This fulfils a similar role to `UQ_Branch_XRef` above, allowing FKs to reference this table by all 3 columns to ensure that all of the values are consistent.

```
    constraint FK_Department_Branch_XRef FOREIGN KEY (GroupID,BranchID)
        references Branches (GroupID,BranchID)
```

And this is the first FK that makes use of `UQ_Branch_XRef`, ensuring that our `GroupID` column is appropriate for our chosen `BranchID`.

```
)

create table Employees (
    ...
    GroupID char(2) not null references Groups (GroupID),
```

This FK constraint is important if both `BranchID` and `DepartmentID` are null - it's our only FK constraint that actually applies in such a circumstance.

```
    BranchID char(2) null references Branches (BranchID),
    DepartmentID char(2) null references Departments (DepartmentID),
```

These 2 FKs are technically redundant, given other FKs declared below, but they're the "natural" FKs.

```
    ...
    constraint FK_Employee_Branch_XRef FOREIGN KEY (GroupID,BranchID)
        references Branches (GroupID,BranchID),
```

This ensures that our `GroupID` and `BranchID` are correct. This FK is only important if `DepartmentID` is null, since in such a circumstance, the next FK won't apply a constraint

```
    constraint FK_Employee_Department_XRef FOREIGN KEY (GroupID,BranchID,
                                                        DepartmentID) 
        references Departments (GroupID,BranchID,DepartmentID),
```

This is the constraint that ensures all 3 of the named columns match up with the entry in the `Departments` table.

```
    constraint CK_AppropriateRole CHECK (
        (RoleID = 1 and BranchID is null and DepartmentID is null) or
        (RoleID = 2 and BranchID is not null and DepartmentID is null) or
        (RoleID = 3 and BranchID is not null and DepartmentID is not null)
    )
```

And finally this is the constraint that applies some business rules about what roles should have which columns filled in.

```
)
```

Comment: I am really thankful to you. My db structure is similar but I needed to add the CHECK constraint. New thing I learnt today. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you tell me one thing that why have you taken two constraints ? We  could write them in one constraint as well  or not ? Please throw some light.

Comment: Which two constraints are you talking about? My example contains 16 constraints spread across 4 tables

Comment: constraint FK_Employee_Branch_XRef and constraint FK_Employee_Department_XRef

Comment: Ok. Consider a role `2` employee. You've put certain values in their `GroupID` and `BranchID` columns and left `DepartmentID` `NULL`. The (implicit) foreign keys on the `GroupID` and `BranchID` columns are the "natural" foreign keys back to their respective tables, but aren't actually required. `FK_Employee_Branch_XRef` is a foreign key back to the `Branches` table that not only ensures that we're referencing a row in `Branches`, but it also ensures that *that branch has the same `GroupID`*. The department one operates similarly when all 3 columns aren't `NULL`.

Comment: My id's are of type int. Will this work only for char type id's ? Because my error has still not gone. I have made changes according to your design except primary key data type is still int.

Comment: @Smokingmonkey - it should work fine with `int`s. I just used `char` to be wilfully perverse (subverting peoples assumptions that primary keys are always going to be `int` `identity` columns)